# How to receive strings using Bluetooth module in 8051

Tags: bluetooth, 8051, keil

I am doing a project on Bluetooth based notice board. In this project, a user sends a message using a voice-to-text app. The message is then received by the Bluetooth module and sends it to the 8051 which decodes it and sends it to the LCD for display.
The LCD I am using is 20x4, so it can display at maximum 80 characters, but if it exceeds 80 characters the fourth line will start scrolling the message.

Currently, the code I had provided can receive 9 characters. How to modify this code for receiving different length strings (as the input message the user provides each time will be of different length)? The code is as follows:

```
#include <reg51.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LCD_Data_Bus P1
#define FirstLine         0x80
#define SecondLine        0xC0
#define ThirdLine         0x94
#define FourthLine        0xD4
#define MaxSupportedChars 20
#define MaxSupportedLines 4
#define BlankSpace        ' '

unsigned int LcdTrackLineNum;    // Variable to track the line numbers
unsigned int LcdTrackCursorPos;  // Variable to track the cursor
unsigned int LcdLineNumAddress[]={0x80, 0xc0, 0x94, 0xd4};

sbit _RS= P2^2; // Register select pin connected to P2.2
sbit _RW= P2^1; // Read/Write pin connected to P2.1
sbit _EN= P2^0; // Enable pin connected to P2.0

/* Function prototypes for UART */
void uart_init();   
unsigned rx_data();
void delay_ms(unsigned int);
    
/* Function prototypes for LCD */
void lcd_cmd(unsigned char cmd);
void lcd_data(unsigned char ascii);
void lcd_init();
void lcd_clear();
void LCD_DisplayChar(char LcdData);
void lcd_msg(char *);
void LCD_GoToNextLine(void);
    
void main()
{
  unsigned char read[10];
  unsigned char i;
  lcd_init();
  lcd_clear();
  uart_init();
  delay_ms(50);
  lcd_msg("\n  Bluetooth based  \n    Notice Board    ");
  delay_ms(2000);
  while(1)
  {
    lcd_clear();
    lcd_cmd(0x80);
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
      read[i]=rx_data();
      LCD_DisplayChar(read[i]);
    }   
  } 
}

void uart_init() // INITIALIZE SERIAL PORT
{
  TMOD = 0x20; // Timer 1 IN MODE 2-AUTO RELOAD TO GENERATE BAUD RATE
  TH1 = 0xFD;  // LOAD BAUDRATE TO TIMER REGISTER
  SCON = 0x50; // SERIAL MODE 1, 8-DATA BIT 1-START BIT, 1-STOP BIT, REN ENABLED
  TR1 = 1;     // START TIMER
}

unsigned rx_data()  
{
  while (RI == 0);  // WAIT UNTIL DATA IS RECEIVED 
  RI = 0;           // CLEAR FLAG
  return SBUF;      // RETURN SERIAL DATA
}

void delay_ms(unsigned int time)
{
  int i, j;
  for(i=0; i<=time; i++)
    for(j=0; j<=127; j++);
}

void lcd_cmd(unsigned char cmd)
{
  _RS=0;             // RS = 0 for Command.
  _RW=0;             // RW = 0 for write.
  LCD_Data_Bus=cmd; // 8bit command to LCD.
  _EN=1;            // Send a High-to-Low Pusle at Enable Pin.
  delay_ms(5);
  _EN=0;
  delay_ms(5);
}

void lcd_data(unsigned char ascii)
{
  _RS=1;              // RS = 1 for Data.
  _RW=0;              // RW = 0 for write.
  LCD_Data_Bus=ascii; // 8bit command to LCD.
  _EN=1;              // Send a High-to-Low Pusle at Enable Pin.
  delay_ms(2);
  _EN=0;
  delay_ms(2);
}

void lcd_init()
{
  delay_ms(5);
  lcd_cmd(0x38);    // Initilize the LCD in 8bit Mode
  lcd_cmd(0x0E);    // Display ON cursor ON
  lcd_cmd(0x01);    // Clear the LCD
  lcd_cmd(0x80);    // Move the Cursor to First line First Position 
}

void lcd_clear()
{
  lcd_cmd(0x01);
}

void lcd_msg(char *ptr_str)
{
  unsigned char i, j;
  int Size = strlen(ptr_str);
  if (Size > 80)
    {
      for (i=0; i<Size; i++)
        LCD_DisplayChar(ptr_str[i]);

      while(1)
      {
        lcd_cmd(0x0C);
        for (i=60;ptr_str[i]; i++)
        {
          lcd_cmd(FourthLine);
          for (j=0; j<MaxSupportedChars && ptr_str[i+j]; j++)
                    lcd_data(ptr_str[i+j]);
          for (j=j; j<MaxSupportedChars; j++)
                lcd_data(BlankSpace);
                    delay_ms(125);
        }
        lcd_cmd(0x0E);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      while ((*ptr_str) != 0)
        LCD_DisplayChar(*ptr_str++);    
    }
  }

void  LCD_GoToNextLine(void)
{
  LcdTrackLineNum++;
  LcdTrackCursorPos = 0x00;
  switch(LcdTrackLineNum)
  {
    case 1:
      lcd_cmd(SecondLine);
      break;
    case 2:
      lcd_cmd(ThirdLine);
      break;
    case 3:
      lcd_cmd(FourthLine);
      break;
  }
}

void LCD_DisplayChar(char LcdData)
{
  if ((LcdTrackCursorPos >= MaxSupportedChars-1 ) || (LcdData=='\n'))
  {
    /* If the cursor has reached to end of line on page1
        OR NewLine command is issued Then Move the cursor to next line */
    LCD_GoToNextLine();
  }
  if (LcdData != '\n') /* Display the character if its not newLine Char */
  {
    lcd_data(LcdData); /* Display the data and keep track of cursor */
    LcdTrackCursorPos++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been abandoned for over a year without information to make it answerable ever being provided.  Additionally this is a protocol and basic programming concepts problem, more than an electrical engineering one.

Answer (score 1):

main() delclares a 10 char buffer for the received data, then receives 9 char to put in it.  You have to change those numbers to accept the maximum expected string.

You should also ensure that the received string has a defined terminator, so the receive routine knows when it has the whole message.

Comment: How to get that string length? Since every time the user sends message will be of different length. And also how to get a terminating character from the voice to text app?